# Is wine from a Miracle Machine subject to Stam Yenam?

Tags: halacha, blessing, technology, grapes-wine, stam-yenam

[This article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/03/04/miracle-machine-water-wine_n_4896641.html) describes a kickstarter for a machine to make wine quickly out of grape juice concentrates. My question is twofold:

1. Is such wine subject to stam yenam?
2. Is it even Borei pri hagafen?

Comment: One can squeeze grapes and make kiddush on it,see Shulchan Aruch

Comment: What about wine from a [Simchah Machine](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0042FIJZ2)?

Comment: Can one squeeze grapes, make them into concentrate, dilute them in a lot of water, and then make kiddush on them?

Comment: Related [article](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/grape_juice_concentrate.php).